# Trying to select second oldest record for each customer and group them by month shipped

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a report which picks 2nd oldest order for every user and groups them by month/year. I know how to select the oldest order for each, but can't figure out how to get the second oldest.

The input data is a table which has every customers' order as a single row with the relevant columns being

```
order.id, order.user_id, order.date, product.name...
```

The ideal result I'm looking for is something like:
mon/year :   number of second orders
12/2013 :       14
01/2014 :       2

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear; do you mean the number of times individual customers placed at least two orders in a month (which I could understand)? It reads more like you want the number of customers who placed their second oldest order each month (why would you want that?). It would help if you could add a sample of what the input data looks like, and then the corresponding output.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm pretty new to this. I'll edit the question and add a bit more info.

Comment: Do you want to count of second older order for every user?

Comment: @SATSON I think so. I want to count number of 2nd oldest orders in each month, and I figured it would be easiest to organise it by user_id

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code

```
select to_char(date_trunc('month',date),'MM/yyyy'),(select count(*) from order where date=min(p.date)) from order p
group by date_trunc('month',date)
```